# Segmentation fault Error comes

Tags: c, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() 
{   
  int n;
  void towers(int n,char from, char to,char aux); 
  clrscr();
  printf("\n\t\t PROGRAM FOR TOWERS OF HANOI"); 
  printf("\n\nEnter The Total number of Disks : "); 
  scanf("%d",n);    towers(n,'A','C','B'); 

  getch();
} 
void towers(int n,char from,char to, char aux)
{ 
  if(n==1)
  {     
        printf("\nMove disk 1 from %c peg to %c peg",from,to);  
        return; 
  } 
  towers(n-1,from,aux,to); 
  printf("\n Move disk %d from %c peg to %c peg",n,from,to); 
  towers(n-1,aux,to,from);
}
```

Comment: Please click the edit link and format your question properly. Also add an actual question, possible error messages etc. You can see in the preview how your question looks, please check it out before posting.

Comment: There is an error message your compiler's giving you. So please include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> scanf("%d",&n);

instead of

> scanf("%d",n);

becuase it requires the address of variable n to the scanf function to store the value.
so,that address is specified through &n.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `scanf("%d",n)` with `scanf("%d",&n)`, pass a pointer to the location into which `scanf` should place the result.